# appendTo custom element not updating with autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange, jquery-autocomplete

I have a search box and am using Jquery autocomplete to get the search results which I want to return to a custom element.

At the moment it appends every time the search changes which leads to duplicates.

I was wondering if there is an option which will delete the contents of the custom element when the search term changes.

```
var $searchFriends = $("#searchFriends");
        $searchFriends.autocomplete({
                    source: "search/findFriends",
                    minLength: 3,
                    appendTo: "#searchResults",
                    select: function(event, ui) {
                        $('#searchFriends').val(ui.item.value);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item){
            return $("<li class='friendResult' id='"+item.id+"'>")
                    .append("<a>"+item.value+"</a>")
                    .appendTo('#searchResults')
        };
```

I currently have a work around which is working fine (below) but there must be another way.

```
        $searchFriends.on('change textInput input', function (){
            $('#searchResults').empty();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `html()` to replace the html in an element (instead of using `append()` to append it).

```
var $searchFriends = $("#searchFriends");

$searchFriends.autocomplete({
    source: "search/findFriends",
    minLength: 3,
    appendTo: "#searchResults",
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#searchFriends').val(ui.item.value);
        return false;
    }
})
.data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item){
    var content =  $("<li class='friendResult' id='"+item.id+"'>").append("<a>"+item.value+"</a>");
    $('#searchResults').html(content);
};
```

Comment: For some reason, this has meant that only one result is displayed where usually there are more results.

Comment: Ah. It's adding them one at a time, removing the previous item. If this is happening in a loop, declare `var content = '';` at the top, then use `content += $('<li...` and then move the last line (`$('#searchResults').html(...`) outside of the loop.